# Why can't I access the auto-synthesized ivar?

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables, synthesize, declared-property

I've been reading that with the lastest version of Xcode you don't even need to use synthesize  to generate ivar, getters and setters, that Xcode itself handles this for you and creates something like _youIvarName for you, however after trying this out i wasn't able to make this work.

Even if i declare my properties, when i try to access these _yourVarName Xcode says such a variable doesn't exist.

example

Header file:

```
@interface ComplexNumber : NSObject
@property  double realPart;
@property  double imaginaryPart;
```

Implementation:

```
#import "ComplexNumber.h"

@implementation ComplexNumber


-(double)modulus
{
    return sqrt(_realPart*_realPart + _imaginaryPart*_imaginaryPart);
}

-(void)setRadius:(double)aRadius phase:(double)aPhase
{
    [self setRealPart] = aRadius * cos(aPhase);
    self.imaginaryPart = aRadius * sin(aPhase);
}

-(void)print
{
    NSLog(@"%g + %gi", realPart, imaginaryPart);
}
```

None of these tries to access those _yourIvar worked... any clues on what I'm not grasping here ?

EDIT:

My main question is, if I declare a `@property` is Xcode going to automatically generate getters, setters and instance variables (with a leading underscore, _myVar) without the need to use `@synthesize`? That's something I read here on stackoverflow and I'm not sure it really works.

Comment: Is the compiler build setting for your project set to LLVM 4.1?

Comment: hmm I haven't changed anything related to that (I don't even know when can i change such a setting)

Comment: Your understanding is correct as of Xcode 4.5 but I'm not sure why you can't access the ivar with an underscore. Have you accepted all the recommended updates to the project (usually offered when you click on the project)?

Comment: Also, try clicking "validate settings" on the project settings to make sure you're using the latest compiler.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 4.5, I believe I've updated everything that was needed... I really don't get what's wrong if that affirmation is really correct. Could you please give me an example of how to work with this correctly ? I mean, this feature of `@property` auto generating ivars without `@synthesize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everything looks like it should work. The one line that isn't valid objective-C is

```
[self setRealPart] = aRadius * cos(aPhase);
```

which should instead be

```
[self setRealPart:aRadius * cos(aPhase)];
```

could that be the error you're seeing?

Comment: I've restarted Xcode and everything is working now ! You were right :) Thanks a lot :DD And yes, that line was a typo of mine, I've already fixed it ! I was having a really hard time understanding how to work with ivars, `@property`, getters and setters @_@